# Custom model permission in django-admin to edit a particular field

Tags: python, django

Normally, after migrating the models located in `models.py`, in `django-admin` you get a set of default permissions for your models. For example:

`models.py`

```
class Appointment(models.Model):                                                            
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

In `django-admin` I can assign these permissions to a group:

`appname|appointment|Can add appointment`

`appname|appointment|Can change appointment`

`appname|appointment|Can delete appointment`

`appname|appointment|Can view appointment`

However, I want to add a new permission to this list that will be able to allow a staff user to change the `notes` field only, such as:

`appname|appointment|Can change appointment notes`

I know I can add it like this:

```
    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            ("change_notes", "Can change appointment notes"),
        ]
```

However, the lines above will only add the permission to the list, and after assigning it to a group nothing happens (the `notes` field cannot be changed).

How can I solve this? Is there any Django extension that can help me add a custom model permission in to edit a particular field?

Comment: You need ensure that the permission has added to request.user.user_permissions or  user's group permissions.

Comment: Yes, but that is my point. I add the permission to the group and it does not have any effect. I know I can get around the problem by making some fields read-only in `admin.py` if user belongs to a particular group, but I wanted to find a better solution, if there exists one

Comment: @6cloud9 did you find a way to achieve this?